# Silly and Likely Simple XSL Issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

My goal with this code is to use XSL to parse a flat file, and so far most of the suggests I've read involve using an XSL 3-based template as its own source.  However, I can't even get basic text to display using the xsl:value-of directive, much less access any other functionality.

I know this is likely a stupid error, but please have at it.

I'm using latest Saxonica 10.5 HE to run the sheet with the following command line options:

`java -jar ~/Documents/SaxonHE10-5J/saxon-he-10.5.jar -s:LinesToXml.xsl -xsl:LinesToXml.xsl`

My source XSL is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" doctype-public="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template" >
        <root>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;Hello, World! It's </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="'simple text that I cannot see.'" />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Hello, World! It's
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't want to supply an XML source with `-s` at all but run Saxon only with the `-xsl` option giving the XSLT file and the additional raw `-it` option to start processing with the initial template you have named `xsl:initial-template`.

As for templates named differently and being in a namespace (e.g. `<xsl:template name="ex:main" xmlns:ex="http://example.com/">`), if you need to spell that out on the command line then https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/using-xsl/commandline/ suggests to use `-it:{url}localname` e.g. `-it:{http://example.com/}main`. You will need to find a way to escape the curly braces if they have a meaning in your command shell.

Comment: I used the command line:

`java -jar ~/Documents/SaxonHE10-5J/saxon-he-10.5.jar -xsl:LinesToXml.xsl -it:xsl\:initial-template`

And I got the error:
`Error 
  XTDE0040  Template ./xsl:initial-template does not exist
Template ./xsl:initial-template does not exist`

I also tried not escaping the colon in xsl:initial-template and got the same error.

Comment: `-it` doesn't need to explicitly name the initial template if it is the one named `xsl:initial-template`. So raw `-it` suffices.

Comment: Sir you rock.

`java -jar ~/Documents/SaxonHE10-5J/saxon-he-10.5.jar -xsl:LinesToXml.xsl -it`

yields:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
Hello, World! It's simple text that I cannot see.</root>`